# WWDP expired and push notifications

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, push, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I have developed an App which uses push notifications. About 2 weeks ago, the WWDP certificate from apple expired... And now the new devices that subscribe with my app are not receiving the new notifications that i send ( the old one are receiving them).

Do i have to upload a new version of my app? or just by renewing the certificates and uploading them to the ACS, will the push notifications work ??

Will they work for the old devices ( which notifications did work ?) and new ones?

Do they have to open the app and subscribe again?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need to do a new version of your app. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/, see if you still have valid APN certificates and if not, create new ones and upload those to ACS.